# How to sort an array using BubbleSort and compareTo in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a code for my java class. It asks to use a given BubbleSort Method and write a compareTo method to sort an array. 
I want to sort the array alphabetically using the names.

I am trying to make an array of just the names and sort them alphabetically.

I'm having problems with the sorting. 
I am getting two errors, 
1. at

```
  Sorting.bubbleSort(array);
```

which says cannot find symbol.

2. at

   ```
   public static void bubbleSort(Comparable[ ] array) {
   ```

which says error: non-static method bubbleSort(Comparable[],int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

I don't know what to try because I'm unsure as to whether or not this is the right way to go.

This is part of the main that is suppose to sort, then print the array

```
   // bubbleSort
     Sorting [] Names = new Sorting [MAX];
     Sorting.bubbleSort(array);

    //use toString() to display the array again with updated data 
    System.out.println("\nDisplay Trees array[] after initializing elements:");
    System.out.println("index    name          height  diameter");
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
      System.out.printf("%-9d", i);
      System.out.println(array[i].toString());
    }    
}//end of main() method
```

And here is part of the 2nd class

```
 /**
 * toCompare() - cast String name to object 
 *    
 */ 
 public String compareTo(Object objName) {
    Trees name = (Trees) objName; 
 }

 /**bubble sort
 * @param array is an array of Comparable objects
 */
     public static void bubbleSort(Comparable[] array) {
     Trees.bubbleSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
    }

 /**bubble sort
 * @param array is an array of Comparable objects
 * @param start is the first element in the array   
 * @param end is the last element in the array */
     public void bubbleSort(Comparable[] array, int start, int end) {
    //flag to see if an item was swapped or not
       boolean swap = false;
      // loop size - 1 times   
       for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
          swap = false;
          //loop from beginning of array to (last element - i)
          for (int j = 0; j <= end - i; j++) {
          // swap if 1st item greater than 2nd item
             if (array[j].compareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0) {
             // swap
                Comparable temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
             }
          }
        //if no swap, array is in order
        //so break out of loop early
        if (!swap) {
           Trees.print(array, start, end);
           break;
        }
     }
  }

 /**prints out an array from start index to ending index
 * @param array is an array of Comparable objects   
 */
     public void print(Comparable[] array){
    //overloading: two methods with same name, but different   parameter type and/or count
    //calls print method with 3 parameters 
       Trees.print(array, 0, array.length-1);
    }

 /**prints out an array from start index to ending index
 * @param array is an array of Comparable objects   
 * @param start is the first element in the array   
 * @param end is the last element in the array  */  
     public void print(Comparable[] array, int start, int end) {
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if(i>=start && i<=end){
             System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
          }
          else{
          //display blanks for proper placement of elements
             System.out.print("   ");
         }
       } 
       System.out.println();
    }
```

Sorry, I know this is a lot and is a bit confusing. If you need any clarity I shall do my best to explain as I'm not so sure of myself with this material. 
Thank You.

**Update:** 
in main() method I changed to

```
Comparable sortarray[] = new Comparable [MAX];
Trees.bubbleSort(sortarray);
```

which got rid of the first error. Then I added static to all methods related to bubbleSort and that cleared up most of the "non-static method" errors, however 1 still persists at

```
public static void bubbleSort(Comparable[] array) {
        Trees.bubbleSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

convert:

```
public void bubbleSort(Comparable[] array, int start, int end)
```

to:

```
public static void bubbleSort(Comparable[] array, int start, int end)
```

Comment: The only error I'm getting now is for the bubbleSort method with the Comparable[ ] array parameter. I've added static to  all methods related to bubbleSort and that cleared up the other "non-static method" errors

Comment: Trees.bubbleSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
              ^
Note: Sorting.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

Comment: @EmsandEms: add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") above your function and see if it solves your problem

Comment: @EmsandEms have this solution finally helped you?